# How to convert List<List<String>> into List<List<Object>>?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, type-conversion

Like in convert how to convert `List<List<String>>` into `List<List<Object>>`? For example `getValue()` returns `List<List<String>>` and then I need to pass this List to Adapter's constructor as `List<List<Object>>`. I don't to generify this constuctor. How can I do that? When I try to cast I get `Inconvertible types` error

```
new TableTimetableAdapter(Repo.getValue());
```

Comment: Should the result be modifiable?

Comment: @dan1st the result of what?

Comment: The `List<List<Object>>` you want. Should this be modifiable/mutable?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting should actually work... You are not allowed to cast `List<List<String>>` to `List<List<Object>>` but you can just cast it it to `List` like so:

```java
new TableTimetableAdapter((List) Repo.getValue());
```

Comment: So I need to just use raw class and ignore this warning?

Comment: I think you can cast to the object you want

Comment: @Vemu Yes, if you are sure that your code is correct, you can of course ignore the warning or better yet suppress it and add a comment about why it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since `List<List<String>>` is more specific than `List<List<Object>>` you do not need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't just cast a List of a type to another type, you would need to map the content of the lists into the desired sub-type.

You could do something like this:

```
List<List<Object>> objects = Repo.getValue().stream()
        .map(strings -> strings.stream().map(string -> (Object) string).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```